# How to stub an object's __call__ method?

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose, fudge

I'm using `Nose` and `Fudge` for unit testing. Consider the following class:

```
class Foo():    
    def __init__(self, some_commandline):
        self._some_commandline = commandline

    def process(self):
        stdout, stderr = self._commandline()
        ...
```

And a test:

```
def test_process_commandline(self):
        import StringIO

        # Setup
        fake_stdout = StringIO.StringIO()
        fake_stderr = StringIO.StringIO()
        fake_stdio = fake_stdout, fake_stderr
        fake_cline = (fudge
            .Fake('SomeCommandline')
            .is_a_stub()
            .provides('__call__')
            .returns(fake_stdio))

        sut = Foo(fake_cline)

        # Exercise
        sut.process()

        # Verify
        ...
```

The error I get is:

```
...
    stdout, stderr = self._commandline()
TypeError: 'Fake' object is not iterable
```

The code I'm stubbing has a return line that looks like this (the real version of "`SomeCommandline`")

```
return stdout_str, stderr_str
```

Why am I getting the TypeError saying Fake is not iterable, and how do i stub this method with `fudge`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stub should be setup using `.is_callable()` instead of `.provides('__call__')`:

```
    fake_cline = (fudge
        .Fake('SomeCommandline')
        .is_callable()
        .returns(fake_stdio))
```

Also, `.is_a_stub()` is not needed here because we are stubbing out the method, `__call__`, directly, which is accessed via the class name `SomeCommandLine`.